# Multiple Ring Buffer for Multiple Points

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, buffer

I am creating multiple ring buffer around points. I am using [Multi Ring Buffer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Multi_Ring_Buffer/) plugin of QGIS. When I am creating 5 ring buffers of a single point its returning a shape I desire but in Attribute Table there is no trace of point information from which the buffer was created. Moreover when I am creating 5 ring buffers of multiple points its returning similar single buffer shape using set of points. But I am trying to get separated 5 ring for each point. Is there any way to get separated multiple ring buffer for each point and having the referenced point information in QGIS?

Comment: The plugin needs to be updated to keep attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The Multi Ring Buffer plugin has now been updated to version 0.3. It will now copy over features if dissolve is not selected.

The update is now approved. So you should be able to install it directly from the plugin manager.

<del>The update is not approved yet in the plugin repository.</del>

<del>But you can download it manually from:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Multi_Ring_Buffer/version/0.3/</del>

<del>To install manually:</del>

<del>1. Close QGIS.</del>

<del>2. Navigate to you plugin folder, usually: C:\Users\your_user_name.qgis2\python\plugins</del>

<del>3. Delete the folder: "Multi_Ring_Buffer"</del>

<del>4. Copy the "Multi_Ring_Buffer" folder from the zipfile into the plugins folder.</del>

<del>5. Start QGIS</del>

Any issues please post to the plugins bug tacker: https://github.com/HeikkiVesanto/QGIS_Multi_Ring_Buffer/issues

Comment: Thanks for the update. It now working as expected. But another issue arises. When I am creating a 5 ring buffer without dissolve its creating five different layers but there should be a option. Currently the rings except the first one is creating a shape not from center. Its a shape that is not circle. its a shape that have center blank. but according to buffer definition every buffer ring should be a circle if created from point.

Comment: Yeah the plugin currently creates 'donut' shape buffers. You should post a feature request to the github repo.